# measure distance between two atoms, in each state, in pymol

Tags: python, bioinformatics, pymol

I'm using Pymol to measure the distance between two atoms of a nucleic acid. I have a pdb. file from molecular dynamics calculation. When I open that file in pymol I have multiple states of the molecule. I want to measure the distance between two specific atoms and for each state, and export the distances to a file. Then I can visualise the distribution in distance. Can anyone please suggest a method to do this using pymol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my attempt , code  using `1m82.pdb` as example molecule and

`` distance("dist_1m82" , "/1m82/A/A/U`22/P" , "/1m82/A/A/U`22/N1" , mode = 0) ``  as distance command (you could use `get_distance` if you don't want/need to create a distance object:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pymol

from pymol import (
                    cmd ,
                    )

pdb_code = '1m82'


print('########## PYMOL VERSION ##########################################')
print('         ',  cmd.get_version() )
print('###################################################################')


pymol.finish_launching()


# cmd.feedback("enable" , "all" , "blather")


cmd.set('internal_gui_width' ,  '500')

# cmd.load('1m82.pdb' , '1m82' , state = 0)

cmd.fetch(pdb_code  ,  pdb_code  , state = 0 , quiet = 0 , async_ = 0)

number_of_states = cmd.count_states(pdb_code)

print('states_count -----> ' , number_of_states)

cmd.split_states(pdb_code)

cmd.sync()

cmd.delete(pdb_code)


distances = []

for state_num in range(1, number_of_states + 1):
    
      
      obj_name = pdb_code+ "_" + str(state_num).zfill(4)
    
      ## PyMOLWiki doesnt show default mode number for distance command https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Distance
      dis = cmd.distance("dist_"+obj_name , '/'+obj_name+"/A/A/U`22/P" , '/'+obj_name+"/A/A/U`22/N1" , mode = 0)
      
      distances.append(('dist_'+obj_name , dis))


print('\n ---------\n')

for dist in distances:
    
    print(dist)
```

output:

```
########## PYMOL VERSION ##########################################
          ('2.3.0' ....

states_count ----->  31

 ---------

('dist_1m82_0001', 5.300721168518066)
('dist_1m82_0002', 5.251534938812256)
('dist_1m82_0003', 5.176976203918457)
('dist_1m82_0004', 5.227502822875977)
('dist_1m82_0005', 4.940760135650635)
('dist_1m82_0006', 5.036609649658203)
('dist_1m82_0007', 5.408339977264404)
('dist_1m82_0008', 5.204244613647461)
('dist_1m82_0009', 5.257850646972656)
('dist_1m82_0010', 5.196445941925049)
('dist_1m82_0011', 5.122419357299805)
('dist_1m82_0012', 5.103713512420654)
('dist_1m82_0013', 5.154935836791992)
('dist_1m82_0014', 5.303188323974609)
('dist_1m82_0015', 5.011679649353027)
('dist_1m82_0016', 5.331982612609863)
('dist_1m82_0017', 5.318058967590332)
('dist_1m82_0018', 5.257812023162842)
('dist_1m82_0019', 5.262117385864258)
('dist_1m82_0020', 5.251483917236328)
('dist_1m82_0021', 5.132598400115967)
('dist_1m82_0022', 5.1809163093566895)
('dist_1m82_0023', 5.067441463470459)
('dist_1m82_0024', 5.514594078063965)
('dist_1m82_0025', 5.220001697540283)
('dist_1m82_0026', 5.40653133392334)
('dist_1m82_0027', 5.2190141677856445)
('dist_1m82_0028', 5.212803363800049)
('dist_1m82_0029', 5.346554279327393)
('dist_1m82_0030', 5.3021650314331055)
('dist_1m82_0031', 5.262298107147217)
```

picture , distances are drawn as light yellow dashed lines :

[image]

As per the

> Then I can visualise the distribution in distance

part of your question, I need to create a `.py` file like:

`runnable.py` :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = [i[1] for i in stored.distances]

print('\n\ny : \n' , y ,'\n\n')
fig, axs = plt.subplots()

axs.hist(y , bins = 5)

plt.show()
```

then add at the end of my first script these lines :

```
stored.distances = distances

cmd.do('run runnable.py')
```

of course `runnable.py` is in the same folder of my main script

this will get you an extra window a matplotlib one like this one:

[image]

where, this need to be checked you'll find the distribution of the calculated distance.

Unfortunately you get an Error too, better a warning like:

```
runnable.py:17: UserWarning: Starting a Matplotlib GUI outside of the main thread will likely fail.
  fig, axs = plt.subplots()
runnable.py:21: UserWarning: Starting a Matplotlib GUI outside of the main thread will likely fail.
.....
....and many other lines.....
```

but at least it'll run fast.

Trying to put the `runnable.py` inside main script or reverting to use :

`from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg`

will  result in:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is ........, parent's thread is QThread(0x7fa9a800cd40), current thread is QThread(0x30374d0)
QObject::installEventFilter(): Cannot filter events for objects in a different thread.
```

with the window showinh the right histogram (the one above), at this point a `pymol` window very slow to load and sending out the message above tens of time.

I guess this second part needs more time to be answered.

**Addendum**

redefining `runnable.py` as `runnable_2.py` so that my script carries:

```
stored.distances = distances
cmd.do('run runnable_2.py')
```

and `runnable_2.py` , copied and adapted from https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/plotting-matplotlib/is:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')

# from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

from pymol.Qt import QtWidgets, QtCore


print('\n\n###################################\n')
print(' QtCore.qVersion( ---> ' ,QtCore.qVersion())
print('\n\n###################################\n')

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, values , *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.y = values 
        
        # Create the maptlotlib FigureCanvas object,
        # which defines a single set of axes as self.axes.
        sc = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        sc.axes.hist(self.y , bins = 5)
        self.setCentralWidget(sc)

        self.show()
        
        # matplotlib.plot.show()


y = [i[1] for i in stored.distances]
w = MainWindow(y)
```

I get the histogram depicted above (now being a PyMOL window , not a matplotlib one) without any sort of error.

While using `from pymol.Qt import QtWidgets, QtCore` and the `runnable_2.py`  QWidgets inside the main script (so not started by `cmd.do('run` , ...)`

keeps being slow to present the histogram and carries the:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is ...........), parent's thread is QThread(0x7f5ddc00cd40), current thread is QThread(0x30ae7b0)
QObject::installEventFilter(): Cannot filter events for objects in a different thread.
QObject::installEventFilter(): Cannot filter events for objects in a different thread.
```

I guess I am missing something like this post for pymol using PyQt:

[Create a new Tk window/thread in the PyMOL session and output matplotlib graph on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29234531/create-a-new-tk-window-thread-in-the-pymol-session-and-output-matplotlib-graph-o)

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. This helped a lot with the problem I had.